# How to filter noise can be heard when electric motor starts

Tags: electric-guitar, noise

When someone at my home starts using blender I hear it in my guitar amp. Noise is single pulse and occurs when device starts and stops not between. How to prevent this other way than switching off all electric devices when playing?

Comment: It's an RF spike - you'd have to identify exactly what is picking it up before we could reduce the number of solutions. Test with amp only, amp & cable [guitar turned down, or maybe just holding the end to prevent the 'buzz'] then with guitar up. Hone down what's picking it up the most.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not convinced it's RF.  The blender would be broadcasting all the time the motor's running.  My guess is the blender is dropping the line voltage and that's causing trouble in the amp.  If I'm right, a UPS would solve the problem.

Comment: You may be right, but I was assuming a 'sparky' switch, which would be broadband RF. tbh, I've not heard of that kind of line drop; I'm guessing it's a 120v thing, temporary power drop. Pretty sure it doesn't happen on 240.

Comment: That would need to be "some blender" to sag the house system. The switch is the most likely culprit: unshielded arcing in open air (see "RC Snubber") However, all motors always transmit RF when operating.

Comment: Note that a cheap AM radio tuned to nothing can be used as an RF "geiger counter"

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/how-can-i-stop-my-lights-from-dimming-when-major-appliances-start-up

Comment: A power conditioner would probably help also. My Furman has a gauge on it and I can see a pretty significant drop when the microwave kicks on.

Comment: I'm wondering whether this would actually be a better fit on electronics stack exchange. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely an RF spike picked up by your pickups. It is pretty common in buildings with old laundry equipment or heavy switch gear.

There is very little you can do about it, unfortunately, but try the following:

- ensure the device is powered off when you are practicing (simple but possibly annoying)
- shield the device (could work, but often it is transmitted beyond shielding by any cabling)
- shield your practice room, or at least the wall between you and the device

Or the best option: buy them a new blender. But before you do, borrow someone else's and test it in your use to confirm it is the blender and not something else triggered by the blender drawing current.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it right know but if it will repeat  I will try this all